# C# Encapsulation - Convert a foreach loop into a linear code

Tags: c#, list, foreach, encapsulation

I have a `List<DrivingData> dataList = new List<DrivingData>()`, where

```
public class DrivingData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

The `List` must be used like this:

```
foreach (var data in dataList)
{
    //Do stuffs with data.Id
    //Do stuffs with data.Name
    //Do stuffs with data.Age
}
```

But I want to the equivalent of above, without showing the `foreach` loop, something like this:

```
public void Do()
{
    //Without foreach, but all statements will be repeated for each data in the List
    Console.WriteLine(data.Id + data.Name + data.Age);
    DoSomethingElse(data.Name);
    DoMoreStuffs(data.Age);
}
```

This `Do()` method will be exposed for users. And users will just put down statements in linear format, each statement will be repeated **for each element in the List.**

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You could try using recursion because memory is cheap these days...

Comment: use List.Foreach directly

Comment: What's the problem with `foreach`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, the `Do()` will be exposed for users. I want this method to look clean and linear.

Comment: @Liren: still not clear. If you don't want that `Do` has parameters but the method has access to the list anyway, what speaks against using a `foreach` in `Do`? The _user_ does not see the implementation. Also, a `foreach` is a very clean way to enumerate a list completely.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, You had a good point. But when I said "exposed", I meant users can create/modify the `Do()` method, not just calling it. They will be told that all statements in `Do()` will be repeated for each row in excel (the List gets its driving data from excel table). Somehow I think that makes it simpler for users without having to put down `foreach`. Hope what I said makes sense to you.

Comment: Which is why I think it's even better if there is no parameter. They can just create `Do()` anywhere without the need to know about anything, besides the keyword to access the List. In my case, I intended them to be `data.Id`, `data.Name`, etc.

Comment: They cannot create `Do()` *anywhere*. You need to know *explicitly* where the `Do()` method is in order to call it. So you should not tell them to create that method, but instead provide a “stub”, which is already at the correct location and accepts the correct arguments, and tell them to fill that.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call the `Do` method in each iteration of your foreach loop:

```
public void SomeMethod ()
{
    foreach (var data in dataList)
    {
        Do(data);
    }
}

public void Do (DrivingData data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.Id + data.Name + data.Age);
}
```

That way, you can put your logic into the `Do` method without caring about that there are actually more than a single item. And the foreach loop in that other method will take care of calling the `Do` method for each item.

Comment: I do not want `Do()` method to contain any parameter. Make them global?

Comment: You can’t really do that. You could make it an instance field that you change within the for loop, but that would make your code vulnerable. Global variables are generally bad. This is the better way to solve this.

Comment: *“I want this method to look clean and linear.”* – The benefit of a parameter would also be that it’s very clean and *clear*. Users looking at the method know instantly that they can access `data` and what that is without it being some “magic” thing that comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Still hoping there is a way without parameter though. My intention is that: Users only need to know 2 thing - 1. they can create `Do()` anywhere, and know that each statement will be repeated, 2. `data.Something` will return that data from Excel (which is already stored in the `List`)

Comment: They can’t create the `Do()` anywhere; that’s not how this works. In order to call a `Do()` method that method needs to exist and be at a *very specific* location. So you should not tell them to create the method on their own (if you already worry about them being confused by a loop, there’s a possibility that they will mess that up), but instead provide an empty stub method which has the correct signature, and provides the correct arguments. Then, they just need to fill in their logic there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
public void Do()
{
    var dataList = new List<DrivingData>();

    dataList.ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Id + d.Name + d.Age));
}
```